# How to create a new product component through onClick of a button in React?

Tags: reactjs, database, react-hooks, textfield, react-props

Goal: Create a new product component through `onClick` of a button where it would display a `modal` containing `textfields` to be filled up with the new product's name and price. We then pass the value of those textfields to the `data.jsx` (data source for rendering the product components) after clicking the `Add button` inside the modal in order to create a new instance of data info of the new product.

Problem: I am having trouble on passing the values of the textfields from the modal going to `data.jsx` since I literally have no clue how to properly pass those values into a plain database file. I think props, hooks, etc. might not work on passing the values.

Modal appearance (after clicking `Add New Product button`):
[image: modal]

Modal appearance (with textfield values):
[image: modal with values]

Modal source code (ModalAddProduct.jsx):

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./ModalStyleAddProduct.css";

function ModalAddProduct({ setOpenModalAddProduct }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");
  const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = useState("");

  const navigateToDraftsPage = () => {
    navigate("/draftspage");
  };

  return (
    <div className="modalBackground3">
      <div className="modalContainer3">
        <div className="titleCloseBtn3">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setOpenModalAddProduct(false);
            }}
          >
            <Typography sx={{ color: "white" }}>X</Typography>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="title">
          <h1 className="modalTitleUp">Add New Item Product</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="body">
          <TextField
            onChange={(g1) => setItemName(g1.target.value)}
            className="inputRounded"
            placeholder="Item Name"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
          />
          <TextField
            onChange={(g2) => setItemPrice(g2.target.value)}
            className="inputRounded"
            placeholder="Item Price"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            sx={{ width: 100 }}
          />

        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setOpenModalAddProduct(false);
            }}
            id="noBtn3"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button>Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ModalAddProduct;
```

Database source code (data.jsx):

```
const data = {
  products: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "MacBook",
      price: 1400,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/180/2400/1600"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Old Car",
      price: 2400,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/111/4400/2656"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "W Shoes",
      price: 1000,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    }
  ]
};
export default data;
```

Full functioning app in CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/addnewproductitem-button-6mtb1o?file=/src/components/modals/ModalAddProduct.jsx

App inspired and based from YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmIdY1Eb8tY

It would indeed help a lot to gather tips and guides on how to handle data passing when it comes to plain database files which only contains a `const array of objects`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would use a state management (context, redux, mobx) or if you don't feel it necessary (because you will not need the products inside another component, or you will not create another level, where you want to pass down the products further), just store the products in a state, and pass down the setState as props as well, where you can easily handle the addition inside the `ModalAppProduct` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right... I think the best would be to use useContext or Redux, but you can also pass the props back to the parent (Main.js) from ModalAddProduct.

Where you have your "Add" button:

```
    <button onClick={sendDataToParent}>Add</button>
```

now add sendDataToParent function in this file.

```
  const sendDataToParent = () => {
    props.sendData(itemName, itemPrice);
  };
```

We are passing all the information we want back to the parent. We could also pass it as an object.

Now back in our main.js file:

```
  const [updatedProductsList, addProd] = useState(products);
```

And we will use updatedProductsList in our map function at the bottom. On the first render, it will display your 3 products you have.

And last but not least... Remember the sendData we send (props.sendData)? Let's update our updatedProductsList that we declared using the useState hook.

```
  const sendData = (name, price) => {
    addProd([...updatedProductList, { name, price }]);
  };
```

Let's "listen" for sendData from the child. As soon as it is triggered the sendData in the parent will be triggered.

```
  <ModalAddProduct
            sendData={sendData}
            setOpenModalAddProduct={setModalOpenAddProduct}
  />
```

Now you need to add an image field for consistency. Ideally, as mentioned before redux could be a good tool to use so you could pass your dummy data there and update them as you go along.
Please note if you try to add the new item to the cart it will show an error. It is because the price on your form is a string, not a number. BTW, there is a concept called props drilling in react, hence why redux or useContext are preferable. I hope this is all clear :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/addnewproductitem-button-forked-8qdx9f?file=/src/components/modals/ModalAddProduct.jsx

Comment: Woah, literally props and hooks can still be used here. Thank you also for recommending Redux and useContext, for now I am just attaining the logic for passing new data into my existing dummy data. I will be using this logic on my main project and will be back once I have used it to tell you my feedback. @pau Thank you for this, this a possible accepted answer

Comment: Update: It indeed worked on my main project! Your logic really indeed helped me a lot for the system flow. In terms of adding the new item to the cart in this sandbox, I just converted the price into a number through ${Number(item.price).toFixed(2)}, found on line 37 in Basket.jsx.

Once again, thank you very much for your detailed and outstanding response for my code issue. Thank you very much @pau

Comment: @RalphHenry glad to hear, happy coding